# Why can't my apache process write to my world-writeable file?

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, cgi

I'm having this problem and I reached a deadlock, I would try anything I've reached a deadend. My problem goes like this:

I have a Perl/CGI script installed on Fedora 9 machine running apache2, this script have a config file which placed in the same directory, this config file has 777 permissions.

The script can't write to the file. It can read but in no way could I get it to write to it. The file is owned by the same user the apache is running. I wrote a small PHP script to test and placed it in the same folder. The PHP script can read but can't write to it.

I'm so desperate here and I don't know where to start with problem, so any help to get me on the right way would be appreciated.

EDIT: I can open the file for editing from command line; it is apache who can't access it

EDIT2: the folder hierarchy /var/www/cgi-bin/script
       permissions are  like this
**/var    root   755

www     root   755

cgi-bin root   755

script  apache 755**

EDIT: **The problem was in selinux. I disabled it and the script had access to the file thanks for everyone contributed**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does apache run with some selinux profile or similar that prevents it writing in that directory?

Comment: im not sure here but i guess yes cuz i tried ps -ZC httpd and i got many httpd lines

Comment: after disabling selinux the php script worked but the perl script ends with an internal server error

Comment: Make sure you are disabling selinux on boot and you haven't just turned it off now to have to return once the machine reboots. (set SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config)

Comment: Good spotting Douglas, I had this exact problem and (as I'd never even heard of SELinux) it took me *days* to figure out what was going wrong!

Answer (score 3):

The user apache probably doesn't have permission to one of the parent directories. It needs to have at least execute permission in all of the directories up to and including the directory that contains your file.

EDIT: Right, considering this is a programming site, some code might be in order.

1. Use the absolute path to the file to test, not the relative one to make sure you're in the right directory.
2. $! should print out a "Permission Denied" error if it is permissions, can you print out the problem with:

   open(FILE, ">/path/to/file/config.ini") || die "Cannot open: $!";
   ...
   close(FILE);

Comment: Apache wouldn't be able to read from there it this were the case.

Comment: Good point, I missed the part about apache being able to read from it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe some other process has a write lock to file? Try **lsof** to see who is holding it open.

Comment: Linux does not support mandatory file locking (by default anyway), so this is unlikely to be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Does the directory allow permission for the webserver to write files there?

Answer (score 0):

I know that a previous post touched on this, but I think it bears repeating: When discussing a problem of this nature it's helpful to include the relevant code and the output of the exception. If an I/O operation fails, $! should contain the system error message, which would explain why the operation failed. Saying "it didn't work" doesn't really give us anything to go on.